# Select input element by name inside a form ($this)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select an input element by name inside a submited form.

```
jQuery('.formBet').on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            match_id: $( this ).children( "input[name='match_id']" ).val(),
            home_score: $( this ).children( "input[name='home_score']" ).val(),
            away_score: $( this ).children( "input[name='away_score']" ).val(),
        },
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        },
        error:function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

I have many forms with the same class, so has to be "this one".

I get undefined value.

Comment: Can you please include enough of the html to allow us to reproduce the problem?  (A guess, though: are the input elements direct children of the form element?  If not, try `find()` instead of `children()`.  )

Comment: And while you set  `var $form = $(this);` you can use `$form`  instead of`$(this)` in the next part of the code

Comment: @ThanveerShah no need to be rude or condescending. Comments like *"you don't know what you are doing"* aren't helpful. That is the reason for this site...to help work issues out like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.find()` insted of `.children()`

```
match_id: $( this ).find( "input[name='match_id']" ).val(),
```

The `.children()`  only travels a single level down the DOM tree while 
`.find()` can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements.

Comment: Should also use `$form` rather than `$(this)` since it is already cached. Both will work, just cleaner

Comment: Thanks! I try $form and find() separtly, but now is working!!